# Screen flickering and freezing after clean install 16.04

Tags: 16.04, radeon, freeze

I just did a clean install of 16.04.

When I boot up the computer the screen flickers occasionally and eventually freezes. I also frequently get corrupted graphics.

My gpu is a **Radeon R9 390**. It is listed as supported by the [radeon driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)*(which is the driver handling my gpu)* for 14.04 and 15.10, but there is no support info for 16.04. It is also not listed as supported by the [amdgpu driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx).

I had 15.10 installed before the clean install of 16.04 and had no problems at all.

Any ideas?

---

### Updates July 7:

#### #1

Sometimes when the screen freezes it switches to a TTY and throws errors like this:

```
[   48.836874] [drm:ci_dpm_enable [radeon]] *ERROR* ci_start_dpm failed
[   48.836898] [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
[   49.008389] [drm:radeon_pm_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: dpm resume failed
```

#### #2

Updating to Kernel 4.4.8 did not help.

---

### Updates July 11

Here is the output from `lshw -C display`.

```
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 80
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
resources: irq:326 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:dfe40000-dfe5ffff
```

I ran `sudo update-pciids` to get this to recognize it as the correct gpu.

---

### Updates July 12

#### #1

I did another clean install. I tried doing a clean install of 15.10 and 14.04 but in both cases the install would freeze. So I ended up installing 16.04 again.

Now when it boots up it will freeze then after a lot of flickering and graphic corruption it will start working again. About every 3rd or 4th boot it will freeze and not come back requiring a reboot.

#### #2

It's now freezing everytime. The most recent time the screen went black and had the following lines visible:

```
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
/dev/sda5: Clearing orphaned inode 262816 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=0)
/dev/sda5: clean, 265908/1831424 files, 1658231/7324160 blocks
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be a power management problem.

Try this;
At the grub menu, press <kbd>E</kbd>.  If you grub menu doesn't appear automatically, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when you first power on the computer.

On the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, go to the end, and right after `quiet splash`, add `radeon.runpm=0` and then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

If the problem is gone, you can make the change permanent by doing the following :

- Open a terminal window, and type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` to edit your grub file.
- Find the line similar to what you edited before, and again, add `radeon.runpm=0` after `quiet splash`.  Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save, and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
- Finally, run `sudo update-grub` to update grub.  This option of disabling power management will now be permanent.

There are also other suggestions in a bug report suggesting `radeon.dpm=0`.

Comment: I don't have a line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. I tried putting `radeon.runpm=0` after `quiet splash` on a line that looks like this: `linux           /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic.efl.signed root=UUID=4f55bcbe-7494-4f1c-97f1-41e8e619a8ea ro\ quiet splash $vt_handoff`. That resulted in seeing the `dpm resume failed` error again.

Comment: @moss Yes that's the correct spot.  The end of that line should look like this : `quiet splash radeon.runpm=0 $vt_handoff`

Comment: that's where I put it. It didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @moss Ok, can you try one more time but with `radeon.runpm=1` instead of a zero.

Comment: Still no improvement when I tried `radeon.runpm=1`

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Well, last thing you could try is `radeon.dpm=0` .  There is a bug report out for this exact graphics card and the same error.  People are posting all kind of solutions https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91880

Comment: Well that is more promising. It didn't freeze this time. Still had few small jumps and flashes, but much better than usual. I'll make the persistent change and see how it goes.

Comment: Great, I edited my answer to include dpm=0 as suggested in the bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm just going to run it through a few more boots when I get to work tomorrow then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Still working this morning and all the flickering has stopped.

Comment: Fantastic, glad I could help out!