# Ubuntu 16.04.2 monitor goes black during start of any game, otherwise fine

Tags: xorg

As the title states I am having issues with the screen blanking, this only happens when I start a game whether its through Wine or Linux native it makes no difference.

> Note: I am using the latest AMDgpu-pro driver stack from AMD(17.10).

```
lspci -v


00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7e00000-f7efffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f07fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at f7f00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f7f18000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2 (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7f17000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f7f10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev d0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7d00000-f7dfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0900000-00000000f09fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev d0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1 (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7f16000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family Z97 LPC Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family Z97 LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at f070 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f020 [size=32]
    Memory at f7f15000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at f7f14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii XT [Radeon R9 290X] (rev 80) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Hawaii XT [Radeon R9 290X]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7e00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii HDMI Audio
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Hawaii HDMI Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7e60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0900000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Bus: primary=04, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

The only way to get back is to do a hard reset which I hate doing, but as yet I have not found a solution.
I edited /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

I thought it may be an issue with the in-built kernel dpm feature, I have tried disabling this with no joy. The following command produces:

```
connected|card detect|primary dev" /var/log/Xorg.0.log

[    13.125] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-0 connected
```

I have disabled screen-savers, power options to never dull monitor etc.

Can anyone help me with this issue, I have switched from a healthy installation of Arch to Ubuntu due to needing the Vulkan libraries within the proprietary driver to run Doom, I previously had no issues with Mesa-git.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have fixed the issue.

I saw the following post:

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/796055/screen-flickering-and-freezing-after-clean-install-16-04
```

I have now edited the following file at  `/etc/default/grub`

I added the following lines of code to disable power management features which seem to causing the issue.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.runpm=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.dpm=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.runpm=0"
```

After completing these changes within this file run the following command then reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
```

UPDATE:

The issue still persists, I can now play games but randomly the graphics will twitch and the screen will go black with no response, requiring a hard reset.

I am literally stuck now with no idea what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, whilst disabling DPM increases performance which is great, the reason for the black screens was completely separate.

Going into `System settings` - `Screen display` - `"scale all window contents to match:"` I needed to select the correct monitor for some reason it was auto selecting `"display with largest controls"`.

I believe this was changing the frequency and resolution of the display during game-play which was causing the black screens, `issue now resolved.`